# AngularJS: rootScope in directives scopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

For example I have directive

```js
App.directive('module', function($compile)
{   
    return  {

        replace     : true,         
        restrict    : 'E',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs)
        {   
            scope.localName = '1';
        },

        template : '<div> {{ name }} - {{ localName }}</div>',  
    }       
});
```

At application run function:

```js
App.run(function($rootScope, $location)
{
    $rootScope.name = "test";
}
```

So in this way directive's scope will be same for all directives but this scope will have access to **$rootScope**:

```xml
<module></module> 
<module></module>
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF8wM.png]

But if I will make an isolated scope:

```js
App.directive('module', function()
{   
    return  {

        replace     : true,         
        restrict    : 'E',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs)
        {   
            scope.localName = '1';
        },

        template : '<div> {{ name }} - {{ localName }}</div>',
            scope : {}  
    }       
});
```

Scopes will be different, but they will be have access to **$rootScope**.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITHr.png]

So I need to isolate the scope of each directive but I need this scope to have access to **$rootScope**.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scope: true`

not isolated, not shared, but a new prototipically inherited scope per directive instance.

http://jsfiddle.net/4LAjf/1

You can log the id of the scope with `console.log(scope.$id)`. With `scope: {}` you'll get, for example, 003 and 004. With `scope: false` (or nothing), the scope is shared, e.g. both have 002.
With `scope:true` they have different id's but can read  `$rootScope`.

In the live example you can see the scope ID in your local variable `localName`. I named the dummy directive `mydir` instead of `module`. It just looks weird naming module a directive.

[More about AngularJS scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Save my life did not know this thing could cause so much problems